# Calculating frequencies manually while plotting fft values

Tags: fft, frequency-spectrum

While calculating FFT(Fast Fourier Transform) of real data, to generate the frequencies I am using the formula:

> **(Index*samplingFrequency)/InputDataLength**

What doubt I have is, in the above formula to generate frequencies should the index start from 0 or one. As, I know that the last frequency of the plot in general is the half of the sampling rate.
So, while plotting FFT values vs frequencies, frequencies should start from 0 or first frequency value.

I am using this library to plot the fft values:
[corban Brook js library](https://github.com/corbanbrook/dsp.js/blob/master/bench/rfft.js)
I get only fft output spectrum values but not frequencies to plot so, I have to plot frequencies manually.
Any suggestion or input could be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: depends on how your FFT is defined. Find the documentation for your FFT, there will be a formula, and the answer to your question directly arises from that.

Comment: @mukhtar alam, while the index can start at 0 or 1 depending on the implementation, remember that the first frequency component is always DC (zero frequency component), so you should adjust your formula accordingly, i.e if your index starts at 1 you should change your formula to `( (index-1)*samplingRate)/InputDataLength`.

Comment: @dsp_user it is my question that should I start index in the above formula from 0 or 1 considering the fft values of real data. For those fft values if I want to plot in chart, the corresponding frequency should start from 0 or some value?

Comment: @mukhtar alam, it depends on the fft function being used. You never told us whether you're using Matlab, Python (numpy) , c++ or something else. Consult documentation for your fft function.

Comment: @dsp_user I have provided the reference to the library used to plot the FFT values. Please check.

Comment: @mukhtar alam, there's no documentation there but judging  by the code I saw there, the indexes start at 0.

Comment: Okay @dsp_user thank you.